# Dynamic NAV Control Add-in exchange data

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Im solving how to exchange data between JS control add-in and NAV.

Now, when I want to get data from JS control add-in to NAV. I call from NAV, JS method and in JS method I call method in NAV. See example below.

Is there some easy way e.g. return values on first call from NAV?
Because I need data from JS in one method.

Thank you for your help.

C/AL Code

```
d::someMethod()
//I need to work with data from JS here
CurrPage.d.getDataFromJS();

d::receiveDataFromJS(data: Variant)
//here I receive data from JS
```

JS

```
function getDataFromJS() {
   var result = 'bla bla';
   Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.InvokeExtensibilityMethod('receiveDataFromJS', [result]);   
}
```

Comment: Looks like fine async code. What’s wrong?

Comment: The async is wrong. Do you think it can be done sync? Thank you

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, I will survive with async. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can return data from your addin via events. Just define the event in your dll and reinclude your addin, it should then be visible in the C/AL. To trigger the event on JavaScript side use `Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.InvokeExtensibilityMethod('eventName', [parameters]);` 
The parameters you parse here can then be used to parse your data to the NAV-side. I hope this helps you